# Markov chain: infinite number of stationary distributions

Tags: markov-chains

Is it possible to construct a Markov chain having an infinite number of stationary distributions $\pi_i$? Maybe also with a finite set of states $S$?

Maybe someone can explain why the following Markov chain has an infinite number of stationary distrbutions (see comments) instead of two stationary distrbutions like $[1, 0]$ and $[0, 1]$.

[image]

Comment: Yes, take any Markov chain with two irreducible classes of states.

Comment: ... which can be as small as two absorbing states and nothing else

Comment: Why does a Markov chain with two irreducible classes have an infinite number of stationary distributions - and not just two?

Comment: You can take any (infinite number of) weighted average of the two stationary distributions to get another stationary distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following, $[1,0]$ is a stationary distribution, $[0,1]$ is also a stationary distribution.

Now, consider their convex combination, that is

$$[\lambda, 1-\lambda]$$ where $\lambda \in [0,1]$ is also a stationary distribtuion. Since there are infinitely many choices for $\lambda$, we have infinite number of stationary distribution.